# Why do some people refer to web views as "native apps"?

Tags: native, electron

More and more I find services that advertise "native" desktop apps, but after downloading or researching find they are web views built in Electron or similar web view frame-works. Are they misunderstanding "native" or am I?

Also, what other terminology can I use to refer to proper native apps?

(My major gripe with these apps is poor performance on my machine.)

Comment: a good clear definition (the first google result though) http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/native-application-native-app

Comment: @AndrewTobilko From this, it seems that web views are not native apps. So the question stands why people keep calling them that.

Answer (score 0):

I think people are using "native app" to distinguish from "web app", which is living within the browsers sandbox.

Functionality-wise a native app build on, say, Electron, should be able to do everything a native app built with C++ and the OS's lowest-level API can do. I'm thinking of things like being able to load and save files locally, use local hardware, or connect to any part of the internet, without hitting security limits or having to prompt the user.

Performance-wise the C++, low-level API, native app should be expected to be quicker, of course.

(It won't always be the case: C++ can be written inefficiently, while the JavaScript programmer might have used every optimization trick in the book. E.g. I thought Atom was slow when editing large files, but VSCode has been quick, even though they are both built on top of Electron.)

Regarding your "proper" native apps question, I guess you would need to also describe what language it is written in, and what libraries and frameworks are being used.

Comment: Isn't it the case that for some new API, Electron or one of it's packages will have to be updated? So for a new feature like Touch Bar, of course someone has to implement this into Electron, right?

Comment: I don't know. There are the core packages in Electron, then there are the HTML5 APIs in the browser, and then there are node packages.  I'm sensing your resistance to the idea, but I'd simply regard Electron as just another API for building an app. E.g. no different from choosing between C++, C# and Visual Basic for making a win32-only app.